# Spring-Cloud-Stream process kafka messages only after the state stores materialized on application startup have been fully populated and ready

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Referring to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931237/how-to-use-interactive-query-within-kafka-process-topology-in-spring-cloud-strea),
My spring-cloud-stream application.yml file has the following config:

```
#application.yml

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input:
  destination: my-topic-name
  contentType: application/json
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input:
  consumer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    materializedAs: my-store
```

Inside my main application with class annotated with @EnableBinding and inside the method annotated with @StreamListener, I am using kafka stream DSL and Processor API integration to access state stores which should be materialized upon application startup because of the presence of materializedAs in application.yml file.

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Object, String> store;

 input.process(() -> new Processor<Object, Product>() {

                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
                    store = (ReadOnlyKeyValueStore) processorContext.getStateStore("my-store");


                }

                @Override
                public void process(Object key, Object value) {
                    //find the key
                    store.get(key);
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                    if (state != null) {
                        state.close();
                    }
                }
            }, "my-store");
```

The problem is that upon the first time when application starts, the state stores have not been fully populated and are not ready yet (e.g empty state store) but the messages still arrives earlier and are being processed by the Kafka stream topology giving unexpected results.

How can we make sure that upon the first application startup, all or specific (user can defined if possible) state stores that have been instructed to be materialized by using materializedAs in application.yml file are fully populated and ready to use before any stream processing topology defined inside @StreamListener starts to process incoming messages. Can we force the stream processing of messages to wait untill the state stores are fully populated upon first time application startup?

I tried to replicate the issue by modifying one of the [spring-cloud-stream sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-global-table-join) and pushed the modified version [here](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafka-streams-global-table-join). More detail discussion on this can also be found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/issues/68)

Comment: Not sure if I understand. It seems you have one input topic and one store. Where should the store data come from that you want to pre-load?

Comment: There are many input topics from which I generate KStreams and KTables and also materialize stateStore. The KStreams and KTables are supposed to be enriched/filtered using data available in state store materialized from other topics. Example in the above, the stateStore is materialized from topic 'my-topic-name' whose content will be used to process messages in KStreams/KTables generated from another topic.

Comment: And you populate it in the same application? Otherwise it won't work. It this two application, it two store with the same name but there is no connection between both. If it's in the same application, make sure that the date from the table topic has smaller timestamps than the record in the KStream topic -- data with smaller timestamp is processed first, and thus it should populate your state.

Comment: I have created a simple spring-cloud-stream app [here](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafka-streams-global-table-join) to replicate the issue. The result of the transformer class is outputted to the console. I outputted the results from within the UserTransformer.java class and persisted the outputs in the following [file](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafka-streams-global-table-join/blob/master/result.txt). Inside result.txt file, the 1st app run has empty stateStore and after stopping and restarting the app again with new messages in the topics, the stateStore is fully populated.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for your insight. Yes, it appears this is happening due to stream timing issue you mentioned. The problem was fixed when I generated the messages for the topic from which the stateStore will be materializdAs on app startup **first** hence giving the messages a smaller timestamp and then the rest of the messages for other topics generated later, giving them a bigger timestamp.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax After resolving the stream timing issue, the application only works as expected for stateStores materializedAs from small topics (e.g 100 messages) but the same problem is arising during the 1st time app startup for those stateStores that are materializedAs from a larger topic (e.g 10,000 messages). Any suggestion why is this happening and how to resolve? I made sure to avoid stream timing issue by producing messages for stateStores topics with a smaller timestamp.

Comment: Maybe related to configuration parameter `max.task.idle.ms` (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3514 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7458)? Default is zero. Maybe increasing the config helps?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the solution. It worked after choosing max.task.idle.ms: 10 minutes for around 10,000 messages in a topic on hit and trial method to fully populate the stateStore on 1st time app startup. I noticed that If I shutdown and restart the app, it still takes the same amount of time (10 minutes) before messages starts to be processed. In production, I may not need to restart the application again and again but when deployed to k8s pods, we may have a situation to scale up and down the app. Is there any optimization to this long app startup time?.Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help me in understanding about how to calculate the value for this property - max.task.idle.ms? What factors do I need to consider while setting up this property?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need join the stream with GlobalKTable(state store), instead of using process interface. Here is the [Kstream join GlobalKTable](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-global-table-join). Please give a try.